# Nesting apps within apps 2sxc 13.12.0

Tags: 2sxc

I have been working with 2sxc alongside DNN (Dot Net Nuke) for some time now.

In previous versions of 2sxc I have been able to use the following code to nest a 'Content Block' item within the text editor field of another app.

So essentially nesting an app within an app!

Using this code as an example:
@ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Render.All(modal, field: "Apps", merge: modal.Body)

Also with creating the 'Apps' as a separate field in the 2sxc app directly below the field I would like to nest the apps inside of.

However, this seems to create an error in the new recommended version of 2sxc.

Error code:
Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ToSic.Sxc.Edit.EditService.EditService.ConnectToRoot(IDynamicCodeRoot codeRoot) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Edit\EditService\EditService.cs:line 26 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.RenderService.GetEdit(DynamicEntity parent) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Renderers\RenderService.cs:line 112 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.RenderService.All(DynamicEntity parent, String noParamOrder, String field, String apps, Int32 max, String merge) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Renderers\RenderService.cs:line 93 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Render.All(DynamicEntity parent, String noParamOrder, String field, String apps, Int32 max, String merge) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Compatibility\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Render.cs:line 73 at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) at ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_LayoutApp__LayoutApp_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\little-seed-dnn\Portals\0\2sxc\LayoutApp_LayoutApp.cshtml:line 44 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 117 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 128 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 135 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.BlockBuilder.RenderInternal() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\BlockBuilder_Render.cs:line 186

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I may be simply missing a using statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code is different now, instead of Blocks or Factory the new way is IRenderService. There is an example of simply rendering the whole output of a module [in to the theme (ascx user control) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437278/how-do-i-render-a-2sxc-module-into-a-dnn-theme).

I think a lot of what you need to convert or adapt is covered here:

#### [Fix Breaking Change in static Render in v13](https://docs.2sxc.org/abyss/releases/history/v13/sxc-static-render/index.html?q=IRenderService)

**Important note:** if you spot code examples with `GetService()` it is now final as `GetScopedService()` and you should use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Please also make sure you don't confuse the `One(...)` with the `All(...)` render methods.

- `One(...)` will expect to get a specific thing to render
- `All(...)` will take an entity which has [Inner Content](https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/cms/content-blocks/inner-content.html)

So I'm just guessing, but you probably want *One*. *All* is basically for WYSIWYG setups, where the editor manually adds any app they want into a WYSIWYG field.

Check the blog app to see it in action.